# SQL View: Finding maximum volume based per day

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view, schema

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
"Date"  date,
ID      char(3),
Volume  integer not null check (Volume >= 0),
primary key ("Date", ID)
;
```

Date is the date the product is sold, ID is the id of the product, Volume is the amount of products sold on that day. This is the sample data inputed into the database:

```
Date       | ID   |  volume  
------------+------+---------
 2012-01-03 | AAA  |   100
 2012-01-03 | BBB  |    50
 2012-01-03 | CCC  |   356
 2012-01-04 | AAA  |    66
 2012-01-04 | CCC  |    99
 2012-01-15 | BBB  |   210
```

I would like to make a view to find product with largest amount sold every day.

Expected output is as follow:

```
Date       | ID   |  volume  
------------+------+---------
 2012-01-03 | CCC  |   356
 2012-01-04 | CCC  |    99
 2012-01-15 | BBB  |   210
```

I have tried the following code but it gives the wrong output:

```
create or replace view Sales("Date", ID, volume) as
select  a."Date", a.ID, max(a.volume)
from Sales a
group by a."Date", a.ID
;
```

I feel like something is wrong on the group a.ID part but I'm not sure.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First group to get the max volume by Date and then join to the table to get the rows that correspond to each max volume:

```
select s.*
from sales s inner join (
  select "Date", max(Volume) maxVolume
  from sales
  group by "Date"
) g on g."Date" = s."Date" and g.maxVolume = s.Volume
order by s."Date"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @forpas I'm new to sql and it can get confusing to write a query with order by when there are two primary keys